# Anime about a girl who escapes torture?

Tags: higurashi-when-they-cry

Never got to watch the anime itself but saw a short 2-minute clip on a profile on Facebook like 8 years back, and never got to follow up on it.

From what I remember:

- It's about a girl who tortures people in her home.
- I remember a scene where this girl almost escapes with a knife, tries to get out the door but is cornered and gets tazed.
- She jams her own head into the knife, exclaiming that she won't allow the girl to be the one to kill her.

Pretty gruesome, I know, but I've wanted to watch it for over a year and just can't find out what it is...

Comment: Can you (edit your post, and) describe the appearance of the characters you saw?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the first season of [Higurashi no Naku Koro ni](http://myanimelist.net/anime/934/Higurashi_no_Naku_Koro_ni).

The scene you're describing is in episode 20 (about 18 minutes in).

[Shion](http://myanimelist.net/character/1313/Shion_Sonozaki) is the one with the taser. She ends up torturing killing like half the cast.

[image]

[Rika](http://myanimelist.net/character/1534/Rika_Furude) is the girl who commits suicide by banging her head against a knife.

[image]

Comment: Yup. A girl ramming her head into a knife is totally Higurashi. @Dark_Web: consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you think it helped.